# How can I schedule my array post

Tags: php, html, arrays, scheduled-tasks

```
$task = array(
        "Monday"    => array("10:11","12:00","23:18"),
        "Tuesday"    => array("08:00"),
        "Wednesday"    => array("10:00","11:30"),
        "Thursday"    => array("11:00"),
        "Friday"    => array("08:00","11:30","23:18"),
        "Saturday"    => array("08:00"),
        "Sunday"    => array("09:00","14:30"),
);
$post = array("post 1","post 2","post 3","post 4","post 5","post 6","post 7","post 8","post 9","post 10","post 11","post 12","post 13","post 14","post 15","post 16");
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($task as $k => $t){
    foreach($t as $tas){
        $arr[$i++] = array($k, $tas);
    }
}
$total = $i - 1;
$i = 0;

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh");
$time_today = date("H:i");
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$dateweek_today = date("l");
$flag = "";

foreach($post as $val){
    if($i > $total)
        $i = 0;
        $post = ucfirst($val);
        $day_post = ucfirst($arr[$i][0]);
        $time_post = $arr[$i][1];
        if($day_post == $dateweek_today){
            echo $post.": ".$day_post." at ".$time_post." | ".$date."<br />";
            $flag = "ok";
        }else{
            if($flag == "ok"){
                $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date)));
                echo $post.": ".$day_post." at ".$time_post." | ".$date."<br />";
            }else{

            }
        }
        if($flag == "ok"){
            $dateweek_today = $day_post;
        }

        $i++;
}
```

Hello,
I have tried schedule my post in array with currently time but I lost for post 1 to post 4. This is result:

```
Post 5: Wednesday at 10:00 | 2016-06-01
Post 6: Wednesday at 11:30 | 2016-06-01
Post 7: Thursday at 11:00 | 2016-06-02
Post 8: Friday at 08:00 | 2016-06-03
Post 9: Friday at 11:30 | 2016-06-03
Post 10: Friday at 23:18 | 2016-06-03
Post 11: Saturday at 08:00 | 2016-06-04
Post 12: Sunday at 09:00 | 2016-06-05
Post 13: Sunday at 14:30 | 2016-06-05
Post 14: Monday at 10:11 | 2016-06-06
Post 15: Monday at 12:00 | 2016-06-06
Post 16: Monday at 23:18 | 2016-06-06
```

Hope anyone can help me this code. I want to schedule my post 1 to post 16 and begin with currently time such as:

```
Post 1: Wednesday at 10:00 | 2016-06-01
Post 2: Wednesday at 11:30 | 2016-06-01
Post 3: Thursday at 11:00 | 2016-06-02
Post 4: Friday at 08:00 | 2016-06-03
Post 5: Friday at 11:30 | 2016-06-03
Post 6: Friday at 23:18 | 2016-06-03
Post 7: Saturday at 08:00 | 2016-06-04
Post 8: Sunday at 09:00 | 2016-06-05
Post 9: Sunday at 14:30 | 2016-06-05
Post 10: Monday at 10:11 | 2016-06-06
Post 11: Monday at 12:00 | 2016-06-06
Post 12: Monday at 23:18 | 2016-06-06
.................
```

Comment: Look, you have 13 dates in `$task` array and 16 elements in `$post` array. Because of that you don't have 16 results

Comment: Yeah! My code task still continues run again after 13 dates.

Answer (score 0):

use this it may work for you.

```
<?php
$task = array(
        "Monday"    => array("10:11","12:00","23:18"),
        "Tuesday"    => array("08:00"),
        "Wednesday"    => array("10:00","11:30"),
        "Thursday"    => array("11:00"),
        "Friday"    => array("08:00","11:30","23:18"),
        "Saturday"    => array("08:00"),
        "Sunday"    => array("09:00","14:30"),
);
$post = array("post 1","post 2","post 3","post 4","post 5","post 6","post 7","post 8","post 9","post 10","post 11","post 12","post 13","post 14","post 15","post 16");
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($task as $k => $t){
    foreach($t as $tas){
        $arr[$i++] = array($k, $tas);
    }
}
$total = $i - 1;
$i = 0;

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh");
$time_today = date("h:i");
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$dateweek_today = date("l");
$flag = "";

foreach($post as $val){
    if($i > $total)
        $i = 0;

        $post = ucfirst($val);
        $day_post = ucfirst($arr[$i][0]);
        $time_post = $arr[$i][1];

        if($i==0)  $time_post= $time_today;

        if($day_post == $dateweek_today){
            echo $post.": ".$day_post." at ".$time_post." | ".$date."<br />";
            $flag = "ok";
        }else{

                $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date)));
                echo $post.": ".$day_post." at ".$time_post." | ".$date."<br />";

        }
        if($flag == "ok"){
            $dateweek_today = $day_post;
        }

        $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, bro :) but it doesn't show correct currently time :(.

Comment: we displayed 16 post. in that you need to display current time? or any one

Comment: Yes, I need to display current time at first task.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE
I have tried to save my task not show.

```
$task = array(
                "Monday"    => array("10:11","12:00","23:18"),
                "Tuesday"    => array("08:00"),
                "Wednesday"    => array("10:00","11:30"),
                "Thursday"    => array("11:00"),
                "Friday"    => array("08:00","11:30","23:18"),
                "Saturday"    => array("08:00"),
                "Sunday"    => array("09:00","14:30"),
        );
        $post = array("post 1","post 2","post 3","post 4","post 5","post 6","post 7","post 8","post 9","post 10","post 11","post 12","post 13","post 14","post 15","post 16");
        $arr = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($task as $k => $t){
            foreach($t as $tas){
                $arr[$i++] = array($k, $tas);
            }
        }
        $total = $i - 1;
        $i = 0;

        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh");
        $time_today = date("H:i");
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
        $dateweek_today = date("l");
        $flag = "";

        foreach($post as $val){
            if($i > $total)
                $i = 0;
                $post = ucfirst($val);
                $day_post = ucfirst($arr[$i][0]);
                $time_post = $arr[$i][1];
                if($day_post == $dateweek_today){
                    echo $post.": ".$day_post." at ".$time_post." | ".$date."<br />";
                    $flag = "ok";
                }else{
                    if($flag == "ok"){
                        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date)));
                        echo $post.": ".$day_post." at ".$time_post." | ".$date."<br />";
                    }else{
                        $save_task[] = array(
                                "post"      => $post,
                                "day_post"  => $day_post,
                                "time"      => $time_post,
                                "date"      => $date
                            );
                    }
                }
                if($flag == "ok"){
                    $dateweek_today = $day_post;
                }

                $i++;
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($save_task);
        echo "</pre>";

    }
```

And result:

```
Post 5: Wednesday at 10:00 | 2016-06-01
Post 6: Wednesday at 11:30 | 2016-06-01
Post 7: Thursday at 11:00 | 2016-06-02
Post 8: Friday at 08:00 | 2016-06-03
Post 9: Friday at 11:30 | 2016-06-03
Post 10: Friday at 23:18 | 2016-06-03
Post 11: Saturday at 08:00 | 2016-06-04
Post 12: Sunday at 09:00 | 2016-06-05
Post 13: Sunday at 14:30 | 2016-06-05
Post 14: Monday at 10:11 | 2016-06-06
Post 15: Monday at 12:00 | 2016-06-06
Post 16: Monday at 23:18 | 2016-06-06
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post] => Post 1
            [day_post] => Monday
            [time] => 10:11
            [date] => 2016-06-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post] => Post 2
            [day_post] => Monday
            [time] => 12:00
            [date] => 2016-06-01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post] => Post 3
            [day_post] => Monday
            [time] => 23:18
            [date] => 2016-06-01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [post] => Post 4
            [day_post] => Tuesday
            [time] => 08:00
            [date] => 2016-06-01
        )

)
```

I have 4 posts not show because it's not valid when $flag == "ok". How to use this 4 posts to continues my task ?